# npx create-nuxt-app return unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

I am trying to install Nuxt app in my laravel project.
My NPM version is 6.8.0.
I have run `npm install -g npx`

```
npx create-nuxt-app cleint
npx: installed 379 in 9.49s
Unexpected identifier
```

Please tell me what i am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most probable reason is, the node js version installed in your computer is lower than required. Install the latest stable release (which is 10.15.1 at this moment) from here https://nodejs.org/en/ and try again  .